# Weird intersection or gap when I solidify

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I'm trying to make a pizza slice in Blender.  However, I'm having some trouble with this, as whenever I apply the solidify modifier, it goes from this [image]to this.[image]  It does a weird thing at the corner.  How to I prevent/fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't have manifold(closed) geometry. you might have 2 vertices right on top of each other which makes it look like its manifold even though it isn't.

Try going into edit mode, hit A to select everything, then from the mesh menu select cleanup, and then merge by distance. you might have to play with the distance setting.